# Remove IOS/Android URL header onchangeevent

Tags: android, jquery, ios, orientation-changes

I'm stumped... I'm trying to remove the url header in IOS for iPhone and Android. The thing is I need that up top real estate and what I see online still does not get the job done.

Here's the scenerio... On the site their is a link to a pop-up overlay. Inside the overlay is my iframe with my content (which is designed for landscape mode only). Show this for Portrait (which works) show this for Landscape (which works). But the URL Header takes up too much space and I need to remove it.

Here's the code:

```
updateOrientation: function(){
    var parentWindow = parent.window;
    switch(parent.window.orientation){
    case 0:
        document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
        setTimeout( function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        }, 50);
        $('section#portraitMode').show();
        break;
    default:
        setTimeout( function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 1); 
        }, 50);
        $('section#portraitMode').hide();

        break;
    }

},
changeParentViewport: function () {
    var parentWindow = window.parent.window;
    var parentDocument = window.parent.document;
    if (parentWindow.orientation == 0) {
        var metaViewport = $('meta[name="viewport"]', parentDocument);
        metaViewport.attr('content',"width=320, height=480 initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no");
    } else {
        var metaViewport = $('meta[name="viewport"]', parentDocument);
        metaViewport.attr('content',"width=480, height=320 initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no");
    }
}
```

}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    this.changeParentViewport();
    this.updateOrientation();
    var parentWindow = window.parent.window;

```
var supportsOrientationChange = 'onorientationchange' in parentWindow,
    orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? 'orientationchange' : 'resize';

parentWindow.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
    this.changeParentViewport();
    this.updateOrientation();
}, false);
```

});

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the browser's navigation bar from javascript?

Comment: As far as I can see, that's simply not possible. I'm not 100% on the Safari browser found on iThings, but I'm certain on Chrome for Android and the Android stock browser. Sorry.